# Custom game or draw loop within XML View

Tags: java, android

I've developed apps and games in the past. Now I'm doing one which is a mixture (don't ask..)
Anyhow I was wondering if was possible to draw a custom loop within the view, example.

I want to do this so achieve complete control loops. Maybe a master loop on top of the view's that's always running (If that's possible).

Relative Layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp" 
/>
```

Within the layout would it be possible to implement a loop as such (obviously in another thread with a bit more code for checking etc etc)

Canvas draw loop

RectF CustomViewWidthAndHeight = new RectF(); //Set using view ID.

```
do
{
    //Using circle as an example.
    canvas.drawCircle(Blag, XY);
    XY++; //An example.
}
while(endLoopSometime)
```

How would one go about implementing this if it's wise too, or advising me of another method.

Comment: Have you read: http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing.html as if you are using custom View there isn't a 'render loop' you can tap into, the framework calls onDraw().

Comment: Thank you for directing me too this, I was looking around but didn't stumble upon this. Make it an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to build your own Custom View. The Android team has been improving the documentation on the Android Developer website. There is a tutorial in the training section on [Creating Custom Views](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html) which should get you started.